# Lookup method in Ordered Binary Tree

Tags: c, struct, tree

I am reading in lines from a text file, storing each line in a node, that constructs an ordered binary tree.

text file:

> 1/12/04 Jones, John $31.11
> 12/22/03 Dickinson, Tony $5.04
> 12/15/03 Lee, Jerry $21.12
> 12/19/03 Kahn, Chris $83.15
> 1/31/04 Bills, Mike $32.00
> 1/15/04 Lake, Jeff $6.66

The order has to do with the amount of money associated with a node. (An inorder traversal would be from least to greatest for the amount of money.)

I have a lookup method that takes a node and searches for it in a tree. If it's found in the tree, return 1, otherwise return 0:

```
    int lookup(struct treenode *whole, struct treenode *t) {
  if(whole == NULL) 
    return 0;
  else 
    if((whole->year == t->year)&&
       (whole->month == t->month)&&
       (whole->day == t->day)&&
       (whole->lastname == t->lastname)&&
       (whole->firstname == t->firstname)&&
       (whole->money == t->money))
      return 1;
    else 
      if(t->money < whole->money)
    return lookup(whole->left,t);
      else return lookup(whole->right,t);     
}
```

The only problem is when I create a new separate node that's an exact copy of what's already in the tree, my lookup method returns 0 when it should return 1. Here is the treenode struct:

```
struct treenode { // transaction
  int month,day,year;
  char* lastname;
  char* firstname;
  float money;
  struct treenode *left;
  struct treenode *right;
};
```

Assume root1 points to a tree that stores each line in a node. Why is my lookup method not working?

```
 if (file1 != NULL) {  
    char line1 [256]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
    while (fgets(line1, sizeof line1, file1 ) != NULL) {

      sscanf(line1,"%d/%d/%d %s %s $%f", &month, &day, &year, lastname,
         firstname, &money);
      // printf("%d/%d/%d %s %s $%.2f\n", month, day, year, lastname,
      //     firstname, money );
      tr1 = talloc(month, day, year, lastname, firstname, money);
      root1 = addtree(root1, tr1);       
    }
    fclose (file1);
  }
  else {
    perror (filename1); /* why didn't the file open? */
  }
 printf("IN TREE: %d\n",lookup(root1,test));
```

> IN TREE: 0

Answer (score 0):

Where do you put the node when it is equal to another? left or right?

Looks like your lookup function is taking the other way when found the equal node, because you have for money > and money <, but not equal.

You need to use the same comparison when inserting and when searching, if the equal is in the right then use the = for the right and so.

Comment: When the node is equal I put it to the left:   if(t->money <= whole->money)
 return lookup(whole->left,t);
      else return lookup(whole->right,t);

Comment: the problem seems to be coming from the lines:  (whole->lastname== t->lastname)&&
       (whole->firstname== t->firstname)&& so I used strcmp == 0 but it still won't work correctly

Comment: In the lookup you have: if(t->money < whole->money) return lookup(whole->left) else return lookup(whole->right), so, if the money is equal it will go and search on the right, and will not find it (and the strcmp is a problem too)

Comment: yes so I changed it to  if(t->money <= whole->money) {

 return lookup(whole->left,t); } but the problem still persists. I'm not sure what to use to compare the names either

Comment: The names should be compared with strcmp()==0, and it should work as is, the other detail that could be failing is your insert function that can't insert an equal node